# context menu for specific filetype

Tags: registry, file-type

I've been trying to add a right-click context entry for .mkv files, I've added a default value of "mkv.custom" to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mkv`, then added(using HKCU because it overwrites HKLM[?]) `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\mkv.custom\Shell\Click To Convert\command` and have "ffmpeg.exe -i %1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy %1.mp4" as its default. The issue is that my menu does not appear when clicking files with the .mkv extension. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

[edit] I wrote this .reg file so you guys can test/help/(I can avoid typos)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mkv]
@="mkv.custom"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mkv.custom\shell\Click to Convert\command]
@="cmd.exe" 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\mkv.custom\Shell\Click To Convert\command]
@="cmd.exe"
```

note some applications use this key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mkv\OpenWithProgIds` so i also tried this, which also does not work.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mkv\OpenWithProgIds]
"mkv.custom"=hex(0):

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\mkv.custom\Shell\Click To Convert\command]
@="cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mkv.custom\Shell\Click To Convert\Command]
@="cmd.exe"
```

Comment: Your defined a ProgID as "mkv.cusom", however you created a registry entry for "mkv.custom".

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, but the entry is spelled correctly, (just a typo here), still having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> ... If you write keys to a key under **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT**, the system stores
>   the information under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes**. ..

So you end up in a verb registration that partly goes to `HKLM` and partly to `HKCU`. Use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\` all along if you want to register a per user verb.